# How can I add a sort function condition that will sort all the blank entries to the end of the list?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm sorting an object array that has a primary contact name, among other things. Sometimes this has a blank value and when I use the function below it sorts it all correctly, but all the blanks go at the top of the list instead of the bottom. I thought that adding the condition shown below would work, but it does not.

```
this.comparePrimaryContactName = function (a, b)
{        
     if(a.PrimaryContactName == "") return -1;
     return a.PrimaryContactName > b.PrimaryContactName ? 1 : -1;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the length is zero?

Comment: (empty string) is what appears in the console output, so yea. I think what I was doing wrong is making the condition on the a.PrimaryContact name and not b.PrimaryContactName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use something like this:

```
this.comparePrimaryContactName = function(a, b) {
    a = a.PrimaryContactName || '';
    b = b.PrimaryContactName || '';
    if(a.length == 0 && b.length == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(a.length == 0)  
        return 1;
    else if(b.length == 0)
        return -1;
    else if(a > b)
        return 1;
    else if(a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `else if(a < b)` should just be an `else` and the `return 0` at the end is useless.

Comment: @epascarello: I like the symmetry, you don't, so chill out.

Comment: @epascarello: And your proposed modification completely misses the `a == b` case when they're not empty strings. Turns out that my *useless* `return 0` isn't so useless after all. Adjusting the first `if` would be an option but again, I like the symmetry.

Comment: It would make sense to change `if(a.length == 0 && b.length == 0) return 0;` to `if(a == b) return 0;`. There is really no benefit in checking length there and you kill two birds with one stone. It is exactly what I did. Still find it funny that the only upvote in all the answers is the one that shows no code. :)

Comment: @epascarello: But then we wouldn't have anything to argue about. I do it just to collect up my special cases in one place. I'm not sorting massive arrays in JavaScript so I'm not concerned about bumming a few cycles. BTW, `vi > emacs` except when I'm talking to a vi user, then it is [`ed` all the way](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html) :)

Comment: You need to have co-workers that think sorting a few 1000 items in multiple dimensional arrays in JavaScript is the best place to do it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Comparison functions must be reflective, transitive, and anti-symmetric. Your function does not satisfy these criteria. For example, if two blank entries are compared with each other, you must return 0, not -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.comparePrimaryContactName = function (a, b)
{   
    var aName = a.PrimaryContactName;
    var bName = b.PrimaryContactName;     
    return aName === bName  ?  0 :
           aName.length===0 ? -1 :
           bName.length===0 ?  1 :
           aName > bName    ?  1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return 1 instead of -1 for blanks.

```
this.comparePrimaryContactName = function (a, b)  {
  if (a.PrimaryContactName == b.PrimaryContactName)
    return 0;

  if(a.PrimaryContactName == "") return 1;

  return a.PrimaryContactName > b.PrimaryContactName ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Your sort function should return 0 if the two are equal, -1 if a comes before b, and 1 if a comes after b.

See the [MDN sort doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more information.

Comment: This still violates reflexivity. Two blank entries must compare equal.